# What are the advantages of using precompiled static library over directly including it's source code?

Tags: ios, llvm, static-linking

The only advantage I can think of is compilation speed. The end result (binary size and speed) in both cases should be the same (unless static library was compiled without optimisations, of course).

Also some references would be appreciated.

**Update:** This question emerged when we had to include small 3rd party open source library in our project. One developer made a statement that including precompiled static library (instead of just copying source files) would increase performance of the App. I see no reason why this should be the case.

So the question is: would inclusion of precompiled library really improve performance of final App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about a third party library, some advantages for them are: no need to release source code, (potentially) simpler installation for end developers... although sometimes it turns out to be *more* of a hassle, especially if it hasn't been done right (linking in other open source projects without fixing up symbols, wrong architectures supported).

If you mean just your own code - seems like you're just creating headaches for yourself. If the files aren't changing, they're going to be compiled on disk already (.o), and the compiler won't need to rebuild them unless you do a clean/rebuild all. So you likely won't gain compilation speed.

Either way - yes, the output should be the same. A statically linked library is just a collection of the same .o files you would have been linking to directly.

EDIT:

Specifically addressing speed of .o vs .a - .a is simply a collection of .o files for ease of packaging during development. Once linked in, the result is identical. I just did a quick sanity test to verify:

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char *something();

int main()
{
    printf("%s", something());
    return 0;
}
$ cat b.c
char *something()
{
    return "something fancy here\n";    
}

$ gcc -c -o a.o a.c
$ gcc -c -o b.o b.c
$ gcc -o foo1 a.o b.o
$ ar -r b.a b.o
ar: creating archive b.a
$ gcc -o foo2 a.o b.a
$ cmp foo1 foo2
```

And there you have it, identical binaries by linking .o vs .a.

There is a slight performance *hit* if you use dynamic libraries instead of static libraries (I believe only when symbols are looked up). Perhaps this is what the other developer was referring to, that static libraries would be slightly faster than dynamic libraries.

Comment: I agree with too much of this answer to answer myself. But just wanted to add that it really depends on who you are and what the project is for. Own stuff, where you own the source and don't have to worry about sharing, then static libs are kind of pointless and just extra work for no payoff. If you plan to release to other people, then they are great for protecting your source code. Precompiled and ready to use.

Comment: I've updated question to better show the context of it. As far as I understand a static library is more or less the raw output of a compiler, so at linking stage it should make no difference whether it's linking against static library or .o files produced by compiler.